NextAuth: Access JWT session data TypeError: (0 , next_auth_react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__.useSession) is not a function
I am trying to access the data from the JWT token just set within my auth.config.ts, as mentionned in the NextAuth documentation, the callback will act as supposed
import type { NextAuthConfig } from 'next-auth';

export const authConfig = {
      ...
      callbacks: {
        ...
        async jwt({ token, account, user }) {
          if (account) {
            console.log('JWT: ', {token, account, user})
          }
          return token
        }
    },
    ...
  } satisfies NextAuthConfig;

As my callback for JWT is set, now I should get access to some data
Problem:
Once in my page, I want to invoke useSession()
export default function Dashboard() {

    const { data, session} = useSession()
    console.log( { session })

    return (
          <div className="flex grow flex-row justify-between space-x-2 md:flex-col md:space-x-0 md:space-y-2">
              Dashboard
          </div>
      );
}

But my terminal is yelling:
TypeError: (0 , next_auth_react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__.useSession) is not a function
    at Dashboard (./src/app/dashboard/page.tsx:21:90)
    at stringify (<anonymous>)
digest: "1797612278"
   8 | export default function Dashboard() {
   9 |
> 10 |     const { data, session} = useSession()
     |                                        ^
  11 |     console.log( { session })

